# when no rows retrieved from SQL database then dont display a div

Tags: php, jquery, sql, html

i tried the empty selector in jquery but it doesnt work. the content is still being displayed. i am retrieving some rows from the SQL database.. if there is no database then i dont want to display that div.

```
<div id="scrollingText">
<div class="scrollWrapper">
<div class="scrollableArea">
<marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left">
<p>
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","fraptech_test","");
mysql_select_db("fraptech_test", $con);
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
  {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
mysql_select_db("fraptech_ndsnotice", $con);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ndsnotice");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row['Notice'];
  }
?>
</p>
</marquee>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: [`<marquee>` tags? Really?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/marquee)

Comment: Just as a heads up, it appears that you're mixing mysql_* and mysqli_* functions

Comment: Why not just render the div if you got data? Rendering it and hiding it after that seems a bit strange.

Comment: Where is your code? Did you try anything?

Comment: so don't output the divs if there's no result rows. `if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) { echo '<div>'; }`

Comment: @MarcB: am a noob actually.. wer do i input your code ? in the <head> or d div? can u show me in code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you guys with ur help i made some change. the below code did it:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","fraptech_test","");
mysql_select_db("fraptech_test", $con);
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
  {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
mysql_select_db("fraptech_ndsnotice", $con);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ndsnotice");
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) 
{
?><div id="scrollingText">
<div class="scrollWrapper">
<div class="scrollableArea">
<marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left">
<p>
<?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row['Notice'];
  }
 ?> </p>
</marquee>
</div>
</div>
</div>  
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is that your whole code? Are you working with ajax? If you're using pure PHP without ajax just   set the output div into your "if"-conditions?

If you want to use jQuery, try:

```
if (  ($("div.scrollableArea p").text()).length > 0  )
{  
$("div.scrollableArea p").show();
}
else
{
$("div.scrollableArea p").hide();
}
```

But you can do it without jQuery, I guess.

Comment: but this aint working... can u edit d code for div id=scrollingText

Comment: The element in the first line is the "source" element. This will be checked, if there is no text inside the element. In my case I assume, the <p>-Tag contains absolutly no text, if you haven't got a result. If you've got a result, there is some text within the <p>-tag. The Element in the third or seventh line will be shown or hidden. Because I don't know exactly, what you want to do, I can't edit the code :-)

Comment: thanx for your help..... i made some changes and got the output.. u can check in the answers.. i hav posted my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the HTML inside your php if clause.

Simple example:

```
<div id="scrollingText">
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","fraptech_test","");
mysql_select_db("fraptech_ndsnotice", $con);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ndsnotice");
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
<div class="scrollWrapper">
<div class="scrollableArea">
<marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left">
<p>
<?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
   echo $row['Notice'];
 }
?>
</p>
</marquee>
</div>
</div>
<?php } else { ?>
<div class="errordiv">Display this on error</div>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home/fraptech/public_html/notredamedelhi.com/index.php on line 132

i.e on <div class="scrollWrapper">

Comment: It have to work ... after `if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {` there must be a "?>" ... should look like: `if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)) { ?>`